# Placing a div below a wrapper containing multiple divs

Tags: html, css

This might be an easy one. Below is a structure which I want to create:

[image: div below the wrapper]

But I always end up with either this:

[image]

Or this:

[image]

Here is my code:

**HTML**

```css
.newdiv2,
.newdiv3,
.newdiv4,
.newdiv5 {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  border: 3px solid black;
}
.newdiv6 {
  width: 150;
  height: 150;
  border: 3px solid black;
}
.newdiv {
  height: 250px;
  width: 450px;
  float: left;
  border: 3px solid black;
}
.divwrapper {
  float: left;
  border: 3px solid blue;
}
.mainwrapper {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="mainwrapper">
  <div class="newdiv"></div>
  <div class="divwrapper">
    <div class="newdiv2"></div>
    <div class="newdiv3"></div>
    <div class="newdiv4"></div>
    <div class="newdiv5"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="newdiv6"></div>
```

This looks like the second image above (in my Chrome browser).

Comment: You need to clear the DIV.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also reset the [block formating context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Block_formatting_context) of the main container, so it minds inside and outside floatting elements.

here the simpliest is to add : `overflow:hidden;` since no size are involved

```css
.newdiv2,
.newdiv3,
.newdiv4,
.newdiv5 {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  border: 3px solid black;
}
.newdiv6 {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  border: 3px solid black;
}
.newdiv {
  height: 250px;
  width: 450px;
  float: left;
  border: 3px solid black;
}
.divwrapper {
  float: left;
  border: 3px solid blue;
}
.mainwrapper {
  display: block;
  /* reset bfc */
  overflow:hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="mainwrapper">
  <div class="newdiv"></div>
  <div class="divwrapper">
    <div class="newdiv2"></div>
    <div class="newdiv3"></div>
    <div class="newdiv4"></div>
    <div class="newdiv5"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="newdiv6"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to clear the `<div>`. Use `clear: both;` on `.newdiv6`:

```css
.newdiv2,
.newdiv3,
.newdiv4,
.newdiv5 {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  border: 3px solid black;
}
.newdiv6 {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  border: 3px solid black;
  clear: both;
}
.newdiv {
  height: 250px;
  width: 450px;
  float: left;
  border: 3px solid black;
}
.divwrapper {
  float: left;
  border: 3px solid blue;
}
.mainwrapper {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="mainwrapper">
  <div class="newdiv"></div>
  <div class="divwrapper">
    <div class="newdiv2"></div>
    <div class="newdiv3"></div>
    <div class="newdiv4"></div>
    <div class="newdiv5"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="newdiv6"></div>
```

Also use `px` after the numbers, else it won't work.

**Preview**

[image: Preview]